# Rotate Entire Scene of Objects at Once

Tags: scene

Is there a way to temporarily override axis and orientation locks and things to select everything in a scene to rotate it 180° at once? I have a scene with 1,500 objects and many are hidden and others have locks on certain rotation axis and drivers. To have to unhide and unlock and remember how to put everything back would be a nightmare. This needs to be merged with another larger scene with a different orientation 
I wish there was a way to put everything in a collection and effect the collection as a whole.

Comment: Would a collection instance work?

Comment: I've been barking up that tree trying to see if it will work. It works in a test scene I made but it crashes when I use all the actual parts in my scene. May try to make a couple smaller collections and try.

Comment: You might be able to write a Python script that rotates everything without the use of collection instances, but the drivers could cause problems if they are orientation-dependent.

Comment: I've been looking into how to do that as well... Trying to find how to do a simple python load blender scene and make it Y- forward I think is what I need. Then I can just resave the scene and load as normal. Or if there is something that is a better approach for the entire scene I'm not sure and still haven't solved it. :-(

Any drivers that break I can just fix.